# Replicate the functionality of 'on delete cascade' and 'on update cascade' using triggers on movies and rentals tables

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Note:Both Movies  Rentals table don't have primary  foreign keys. Use only trigger to implement  above.

Movie Tables

```
ID   Title                      Category
1   ASSASSIN'S CREED EMBERS     Animations
2   Real Steel                  Animations
3   Alvin   Chipmunks           Animations
4    Adventures of Tin Tin      Animations
5   Safe                        Action
6   Safe House                  Action
7   GIA                         18
8   Deadline 2009               18
9    Dirty Picture              18
10  Marley  me                  Romance
```

Rentals tables

```
memid First_name  Last_name  Movieid
1     Alicia      Alarcon     1
2     Don         Draper      2
3     Lizzie      Moss        5
4     Eldon       Chance      8
5     Jenny       Patterson   10
6     Craig       Daniels     Null
7     Denny       Pattinson   Null
```

Since I am a beginner in SQL, therefore, I couldn't form a proper query. T tried till this much.

```
Create trigger 'movren_trg'
After Update on 'Movies' and 'Rentals'
For each row
Begin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_movies_update
AFTER DELETE ON movies
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE rentals
    SET movieid = id
    WHERE movieid = OLD.id ;
END;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_movies_delete 
AFTER DELETE ON movies 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM  rentals
    WHERE movieid 
    NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM movies);
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `rentals_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `rentals` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
delete from movies
where id=old.movieid;
END

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `movies_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `movies` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE RENTALS
SET MOVIEID=NEW.ID
WHERE MOVIEID=OLD.ID;

END